# How to disable using hardware acceleration in my phonegap Android application?

Tags: android, cordova

I have made an Android application using PhoneGap and now I am testing it on Android device.
I am using Foundation, and I am not using JavaScript, as that slows down the animations.
Ok, now I have built the application, connected with my Android and built on my cell phone using Eclipse - and **it it terribly slow!**

I have removed all JavaScript as I have read it slows down the app. The solution I have found on the internet is to `disable` hardware acceleration, but I am `not being able to do tha`t. I set in the manifest, run from eclipse, but it seems that it is not having any effect, and also my Manifest file gets overwritten, I don't know who overwrites it and how.

**The questions is** - how to disable hardware acceleration in the app, and how to speed up the application?

And will creating a release file speed up the app ? (when I disable debugging - if I would know how :) )

Any help is appreciated

Comment: not sure about hardwareacceleration, but I know that building a release build will improve performance

Comment: I think it will, but is there a way to see it before building a release, as I am having trouble to build unsigned app and installing on my phone

Comment: I am able to deploy to my phone by having it plugged into my computer, having 'usb debug' set and running `cordova run android`

Comment: Thanks @DawsonLoudon for the help. I can run on my android using `phonegap local build android` but it looks like I am missing something to speed up the app. I will investigate, and if I find, I will post it here for the reference. Thanks for chatting, it is good to know that someone also tries to help ;) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is this:

You can change hardware acceleration inside your `phonegap_directory/www/config.xml` adding line stated below
and you should change ONLY that file as any other change could be overwritten.

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest"> <application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" /> </gap:config-file>
```

But most important answer is this: I have tried to disable hardware acceleration due to performance issues, BUT it turns out that **the main problem with the performance was in CSS**. When I used other CSS techniques, then I have done earlier, and optimized CSS elements, the performance boosted for about 200%. So the main problem is in CSS even though this was question how to speed up by disabling hardware acceleration.

Comment: That would be nice to describe or give reference to those CSS techniques. Are you referring to using `translateZ` or things like that to create rendering layers?

Comment: There is no single reference, and mostly I have done the optimization and testing myself with various CSS options turned on and off. In general which gave most of the improvement was removing a `shadow` and any of such kind options. The second thing that gave the most improvement was to use different "movement" techniques. There are translate, translate3d, transform etc. I can't remember which gave the most of the improvements, but as far as I can recall, that really depends on whether a a 3D acceleration is turned off or on in the configuration, but please double check that.

Comment: This is not an answer. You don't give the xml element to add to the config.

Comment: Thanks Robert, the xml is just a side note, the answer is located in the next paragraph, have you read it?

Comment: it would be nice though, to know what the xml config value for disabling hardware acceleration is, it's been hard to find anywhere, most references say to patch the actual manifest

Comment: In my case removing reference to `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` immediately improved visual performance. I have a plugin called `WebPullToRefresh` which did a lot of transforms, removing this `js` plugin fixed the issue entirely.

Comment: @Aleks your second paragraph is not the answer, as it has nothing to do with the hardware acceleration config.xml / AndroidManifest.xml documents. Please complete your answer or edit your original question.

Comment: @THEAMAZING It is still the answer. Even-though I have asked about hardware acceleration and to avoid falling into the XY-Problem http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem I have stated that the problem of the speed might not be fixed by just disabling the hardware acceleration, but also avoiding certain CSS properties

Comment: Its the answer to your problem but the problem you had is not the problem in the title. edit it.

Comment: I have edited the answer to match the question and left my additional comment for the matter, before your comment. Read it before commenting. @THEAMAZING

Answer (score 1):

Add this to config.xml

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest"> <application
android:hardwareAccelerated="false" /> </gap:config-file>
```

Don't forget to add this:

> xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

... right after

> http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap =
>   "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"

....

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how-can-i-disable-hardware-acceleration-on-android-on-phonegap-build

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to solve the problem.  In ran into this example config.xml on the cordova site [example](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config-example/blob/master/config.xml).  It has the following lines

```
<platform name="android">
    ...
    <preference name="android-manifest/application/@android:hardwareAccelerated" value="custom" />
    <preference name="android-manifest/@android:hardwareAccelerated" value="custom" />
    ...
```

It does not seem to convert the xml to the android manifest file using phonegap 6.4.2 but perhaps it works with cordova itself or Adobe's phonegap build